# Detect image load

Tags: jquery, image-load

Is it possible to detect once an image has been loaded with jQuery?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event handler, like this:

```
$("#myImg").load(function() {
  alert('I loaded!');
}).attr('src', 'myImage.jpg');
```

Be sure to attach it *before* setting the source, or the event may have fired before you attached a handler to listen for it (e.g. loading from cache).

If that's *not* doable (setting the `src` after binding), be sure to check if it's loaded and fire it yourself, like this:

```
$("#myImg").load(function() {
  alert('I loaded!');
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this: `$("#myImg").live("load", function(){ //dance });`"

Comment: Unfortunately, `.load()` is deprecated as of jQuery v1.8

Comment: @CummanderCheckov it was deprecated due to ambiguity between the event handler and the ajax content fetcher.  In the above code just replace `.load(` with `.on('load',` for equivalent functionality in 1.7+.

Comment: I've been banging my head on this for hours. Thank you @NickCraver. We have an ad image that is dynamically loaded from an ad server, so no control on our side. I was able to use this to test for it to properly load, so I could use JS to center it horz/vert.

Comment: Hi Nick, how cross browser compatible is this? Works on IE8, IE9 reliably? And secondly, will the handler fire if the image is loaded instantly from browser cache?

Comment: I used to be able to run `$("#myImg").on('load',` at any time during page load but now in Google Chrome I have to call it within `$(document).on('ready',` for it to trigger correctly every time. I als have put a dynamic query string on the image source to make it more reliable. It seemed to be playing up a bit. `<img src="pic.jpg?<?php echo time(); ?>">`

Answer (score 21):

It's just as simple to use plain Javascript:

```
  // Create new image
var img = new Image();

  // Create var for image source
var imageSrc = "http://example.com/blah.jpg";

  // define what happens once the image is loaded.
img.onload = function() {
    // Stuff to do after image load ( jQuery and all that )
    // Within here you can make use of src=imageSrc, 
    // knowing that it's been loaded.
};

  // Attach the source last. 
  // The onload function will now trigger once it's loaded.
img.src = imageSrc;
```

Comment: this fails when checking images that are already in the Cache.

Answer (score 6):

I've been also researching this for long time, and have found this plugin to wonderfully
help with this: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

It seems like an aweful lot of code, but...I found no other way for checking when an image has been loaded.

Answer (score 6):

Using jQuery on('load') function is the right way to check if the image is loaded. But be aware that the on('load') function will not work if the image is already in cache.

```
var myImage = $('#image_id');
//check if the image is already on cache
if(myImage.prop('complete')){ 
     //codes here
}else{
     /* Call the codes/function after the image is loaded */
     myImage.on('load',function(){
          //codes here
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with jquery:

```
$('img').load(function(){
   //do something
});
```

If tried it with:

```
$('tag')html().promise().done(function(){ 
   //do something
}) ;
```

but that will not check if the picture is load. That fire done if the code is load. Otherwise you can check if code was done then fire the img load function and check if picture is really loaded. So we do a combination of both:

```
$('tag')html('<img src="'+pic+'" />').promise().done(function(){ 
   $('img').load(function(){
     //do something like show fadein etc...
   });
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you a bit:

```
    $('img').error(function(){
        $(this).attr( src : 'no_img.png');
 })
```

So, if it loaded - will be shown original image. In other - will be shown image, that contains fact with crashed image or 404 HTTP Header.