# check if multiple images loaded within certain timeinterval; if not then replace with other url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem- I am displaying some images on a page which are being served by some proxy server. In each page I am displaying 30 images ( 6 rows - 5 in each row). Here if due to overload  or due to any other issue if proxy server could not able to server images( either all images or some of them) in 6 seconds then I want to replace unloaded image url with some other url using javascript so that I could display 30 images at the end.

What I tried is below.

```
objImg = new Image();
objImg.src = 'http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-4.jpg';

if(!objImg.complete)
  { 
     alert('image not loaded');
  }else{
     img.src = 'http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-4.jpg';
  }
```

I also tried with below code.

```
$('img[id^="picThumbImg_"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).load()) {
            //it will display loaded image id's to console
            window.console.log($(this).attr('id'));
        }
    });
```

I could not use set time-out for each image because it will delay all page load.

I checked other similar question on stack-overflow but no solution worked me perfectly as I need to display multiple images.Please guide how to proceed.

Comment: Check the `error` method http://api.jquery.com/error/

Comment: How about an image loader [such as this (YAIL)](https://github.com/AbdiasSoftware/YAIL-imageLoader-for-JavaScript). That will deal with bulk loading and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to wait 6 seconds, or using TimeOut. You can check if the images are loaded or not using the `onload` Javascript/Jquery event. I know, it will take a little bit to dispatch the `onerror` event, let see:

### Why don't use the `load` Jquery event on the window or the image itself?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //check each image
})
```

**Disadvantage**:

- It will wait for other resources like scripts, stylesheets & flash, and not just images, which may or may not be OK to you.
- If the image loads from the cache, some browsers may not fire off the event (included yours and that's why your code is not working)

### Why don't use the `error` Jquery event on the image itself?

```
$('img[id^="picThumbImg_"]').error(function(){
       //image loading error
})
```

**Disadvantages:**

- It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
- It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
- It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
- Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

**Note:**: Error is almost the same that the load event

### Improving the code!:

```
$('img[id^="picThumbImg_"]').one('error', function() {
   // image load error
}).each(function() {
   if(!this.complete) $(this).error();
});
```

This will avoid few things of the previous code, but you still will have to wait if it's a 404 and you're replacing it in the `onerror` event, that will take a little bit right?

### So, what now!

You can use this [awesome plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)!. Once you add the reference, you just have to use something like:

```
var imgLoad = imagesLoaded('#img-container');
imgLoad.on( 'always', function() {
  // detect which image is broken
  for ( var i = 0, len = imgLoad.images.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if(!imgLoad.images[i].isLoaded){
       //changing the src
       imgLoad.images[i].img.src = imgLoad.images[i].img.getAttribute("data-src2");
    }
  }
});
```

Your HTML markup should look like:

```
<div id="img-container">
    <div class="row">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <img src="original-path.jpg" data-src2="alternative-path.jpg">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** You don't need jQuery in this case and this plugin is suggested by Paul Irish ;)

Comment: Sounds good but where we are considering the time-interval for the case where multimedia proxy server is slow or it will consider this delay ?Actually I m confused with your first line. I need to use this inside a function which get invoked after 6 seconds.

Comment: @virus: I'm not sure... try it and let me know ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I am done with the my task.

Answer (score 0):

Give all your images a specific class. Loop through your images and use .load() to check if loaded, example below...

[Detect image load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537469/jquery-detect-when-image-has-loaded)

Comment: @RealityDysfunction- You are detecting when image is loaded. My problem is different. If any image has not been loaded in 6 seconds then load image from other src. Also note it that I need to load multiple images ( 30 in a page).

Comment: There is a timeout function, give it 6 seconds and you should be good.