# Attach jquery call to image load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to incorporate a script (written by "dystroy" I believe) that centers an image vertically within a div with the overflow hidden. It works quite well but many of my images are dynamically loaded upon mouseover.

I need to find a way to call the script upon image load. It's been two days now and as JS/JQuery aren't my native language, I find my self here.

Can anyone suggest how I might get the following to fire on image load?
Many thanks!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.container').each(function () {
    var $img = $(this).find('img');
    $(this).scrollTop(($img.height() - $(this).height()) / 2);
    $(this).scrollLeft(($img.width() - $(this).width()) / 2);
  });
});
//]]></script>
```

Comment: What code are you using to dynamically load images?

Comment: It's an Image Cycler - OpenCart - functions on mouseover

Comment: This question is very similar to [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537469/jquery-detect-when-image-has-loaded).  The answer describes how to detect when an image has loaded, which you can then use to fire your event.

Comment: I think your question has already been answered here:

[jQuery callback on image load (even when the image is cached)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions! JPDurham, Quinn & clancer looking into them now

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could combine the load api (https://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$("#book").load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

with the event delegation to make it so that any new images loading inside one of your specified divs get an onload function applied to them (https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
// attach a delegated event
$("#list").on("click", "a", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(...` Will wait until everything on the page is loaded (including the images) before executing the function.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.container').each(function () {
    var $img = $(this).find('img');
    $(this).scrollTop(($img.height() - $(this).height()) / 2);
    $(this).scrollLeft(($img.width() - $(this).width()) / 2);
    });
});
//]]></script>
```

Comment: I believe the images are dynamically loaded after the page which is the issue of this question, see my answer for how this can be resolved

Comment: Could you load the images before and hide them maybe? then do what I have done.

Comment: Appreciated Maximilian but clancer is correct in that the script must be called upon image load. I have far too many images involved for preload.