# Checking images are fully loaded

Tags: jquery

I got below jquery snippets for check the image are loaded and its working fine, I want to know any possibility to check the else case like image is not loaded with below snippet.

```
<img id="proPic" src="">
$('#proPic').attr('src', imgurl).load(function() {
     alert('Image Loaded');
    });
```

Comment: may you try to execute the script like: if image exists than start a timer and give this timer e.g. 4 sec to check if image loaded

Comment: you may check this accepted answere here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537469/jquery-detect-when-image-has-loaded

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery **error()** to achieve this task, try following:

```
$('img').error(function() {
    this.src = 'some_default_image_source';
});
```

Comment: i think i tried this one in the past and ran into some probems. Check szenarios like: Image is e.g. 5mb or bigger and takes time to load....