# jquery load image into div strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I've made slideshow with thumbnails at it's side.

Here, basically a div which displays the image and after clickimg on a particular thumbnail, it's related picture will be dynamically displayed in the main div (`#display #slideshowpic`). Here is the code example,

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="display">
      <img id="slideshowpic" src="initial.jpg">
    </div>

    <div id="thumbs">
      <img class="thumb" id="image1">
      <img class="thumb" id="image2">
      <img class="thumb" id="image3">
      <img class="thumb" id="image4">
      <img class="thumb" id="image5">
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript,

```
$('.thumb').click( function() {
        $('#slideshowpic').attr('src',"");   /// clears or removes current image
        $('#slideshowpic').attr('src',"/uploads/" + $(this).attr('id') + ".jpg");
});
```

Here, the image which is to be loaded in the main div after clicking thumbnail, is [progressive image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_scan) which is interlanced with `php gd`.

This is  working perfectly in firefox. After clicking thumbnail, the image instantly displays in the main div with progressive fasion. But it doen't seems to be working in chrome.

The Problem is (chrome) : After clicking the thumbnail; first the image is cleared as per the code, then the **previous image** displays instead of new image (clicked image) and then new image displays after taking some time delay (i think the delay is the time which new image is taking to load).

google chrome doesn't show image till it loads image fully

I just can't figure out where is the problem is. Should i use another technique to load that dynamic image.. ? please help. I stucked in it from many days.

**EDIT :** you can check it in below links,

- http://bit.ly/ZxVCM3
- http://bit.ly/1oeutK5
- http://bit.ly/1rIxvAV

Click the thumbnails to load the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` without `src` has no reason...

```
$('.thumb').click( function() {

        var img = $('#slideshowpic');
        var src = $(this).attr('id');

        img.css('opacity','0').on('load', function() { 
             $(this).fadeIn();
        }).attr('src',"/uploads/" + src + ".jpg");


});
```

from [Detect image load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537469/detect-image-load)

Comment: what is the need of `setTimeout( function() {img.fadeIn()}, 500);
`

Comment: I'm having css3 animated div as a background of the div instead of  `loader gif`. So there is not need of that gif. when image would be loaded then it will automatically hidden by it.

Comment: to wait, while image is loading. You'll show the image 0.5sec after changing `src`

Comment: why use of wait instead the image should be displayed in progressively.

Comment: "Detact image load" function will fired when the whole image will load. But i want to display image in progressive fashion. Since the image is too big.

Comment: You can try `.remove()` whole img tag and `.append()` new one

Answer (score 0):

Seems like firefox uses the image cache and chrome doesn't.
I have used magnific popup, 
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/
It has a built-in prefetch for galleries.

Comment: I can't use any readymade plugins. since i'm having only problem with chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
img = new Image(); // this is important
img.src = src; // new src for the image.
img.onload = function () {
    //Your logic. Replace the original image with the new one.
};
```

Instead of modifying the `src` of the image, try replacing the `img` tag with the new one when the new image is loaded. This should work for you. The issue is mainly because of the caching in chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why it's not displaying the image in progressive fashion. Instead it is displaying after whole image is loaded.