# How can I load an external html with <img> and display it with jquery, when everything is loaded?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a loading problem with external html and images. I want to load an external html (`examplework.html`) in a overlay-div, and when its totally loaded, i want to show it.

So the actual status is:

Jquery call on a Click-Event in the Main-HTML-Page:

```
$('#overlaycontent').load("examplework.html", function() {
    $('#overlaycontent').removeClass("loadingwork").addClass('loadedwork');
});
```

The examplework.html looks like this:

```
<div class="workdetail">
   <p>TEXT</p>
   <img class="extimgload" src="http://mydomain.de/works/1.jpg" alt="Description">
   <img class="extimgload" src="http://mydomain.de/works/2.jpg" alt="Description">
   <img class="extimgload" src="http://mydomain.de/works/3.jpg" alt="Description">
</div>
```

The Main Html-Page and the example.work are in the same folder.
The `src` attributes of the images are absolute paths (because relative paths could cause problems, i`ve read in another discussion here)

Now the `examplework.html` is loaded and then displayed instead of a loading. That works fine. But the images are not yet loaded, so I see the 3 alt-descriptions and then they are replaced with the images, when each is ready loaded.

But I want to show the overlay, when everything is loaded.
Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Add a event load on your class. Please try: work fine for me

```
$('#overlaycontent').load("content.html", function() {
        $(".extimgload").on('load', function() {    
             $('#overlaycontent').removeClass("loadingwork").addClass('loadedwork');
        })
    });
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    count=0;
    $('#overlaycontent').load("content.html", function() {
        $(".extimgload").each(function() { 
            $(this).on('load', function() { 
                call();
            })
        })

    }); 
    function call(){
        count++;
        if (count == $(".extimgload").length)
            $('#overlaycontent').removeClass("loadingwork").addClass('loadedwork');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thts works fine with one Image, but i could have 3 or 10 or 20 images. 
So the callback has to be executed on the last element.

Answer (score 0):

this can work (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537469/detect-image-load)):

```
$('#overlaycontent').load("examplework.html", function() {
        $(".extimgload").load(function() {
          $('#overlaycontent').removeClass("loadingwork").addClass('loadedwork');
        }).each(function() {
          if(this.complete) $(this).load();
        });
});
```

look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyhg5skj/)

Answer (score 0):

Now i have a dirty looking solution, based on P.Franks solution.

```
var count = 0;

$('#overlaycontent').load("examplework.html", function() {  
    $('.extimgload').each(function() {
        count ++;
    });

    $('.extimgload').on('load', function() {    
        showOverlay();
    });
});  

var showOverlay = function() { 
    count --;
    if (count == 0) {
        $'#overlaycontent').removeClass("loadingwork").addClass('loadedwork');
        $('#overlayshadow').removeClass("showloadi");
    }           
};
```