# Updating image source on load in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'd like to do is run a function that returns a result and then use that result as the src for an image when the page loads. I'm running into issues having it work though

So my code is:

```
<img id="adult_total" src="/assets/media/images/AsExpected.png">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var imgsource = $('#ProgramSummaryController').scope().getOutcomeRatingImage(getOutcomeDataForKey('GraftTotal'));
   $('#adult_total').attr("src", imgsource);    
  });           
</script>
```

where ProgramSummaryController is the ng-controller of the surrounding div. I don't see any errors in console so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: Please show us ProgramSummaryController

Comment: use load event : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537469/detect-image-load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537469/detect-image-load)