# Change image source (twice) when src does not exist

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, vue-component, src

I just started using **Vue** in the **front-end of my website**.
In one of my Vue-components I want an image with a certain path:

```
<img src="path/example/with/vue/var">
```

Now, this is what I want to do:

> - Check if the file in "path/example/with/vue/var" exists
> - If not: Change the src to "another/path/with/vue/var"
> - Check if "another/path/with/vue/var" exist
> - If not: Change the src to "default/path"

I already tried to use `onerror` with a function inside of it. But the problem is I'm loading 100+ objects with a couple of images for each object. If I just check if the file exists the normal way(through Ajax or with an XMLHttpRequest), the performance is completely gone. All objects are loaded through a JSON file.

I hope you guys understand the question.

Comment: new Iamge, abd image load event,

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537469/detect-image-load

Comment: put easy demo, give time and try to make second try

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

You can understand if the path exist in this way

```
$('#container').imagesLoaded()
  .always( function( instance ) {
    console.log('all images loaded');
  })
  .done( function( instance ) {
    console.log('all images successfully loaded');
  })
  .fail( function() {
    console.log('all images loaded, at least one is broken');
  })
```

In the Fail function you can re-make imagesLoaded() for another path and so on

Comment: Yes you can use also Vanilla

Comment: Like Alvaro said, I'm using vue so I'm just going to use vanilla instead of jQuery

Comment: @Irrech $=jquery

Comment: imagesLoaded( document.querySelector('#container'), function( instance ) {
  console.log('all images are loaded');
});

Comment: With imagesloaded you can check all images together if you use the container, or the single element, use this function for all element

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to implement this would be to make a component out of the object you are using in your `v-for` loop.

Then you can simply used a computed property to check the `src` property on your object.

in this case you do:

```
const image = new Image()
```

And then set the src like so:

```
image.src = <object>.src
```

After you have set the src on the Image object you could then check if your specified image has loaded with `onload` or has failed with `onerror`.

I do something similarly in my code by check if an image has loaded or not so I can replace the placeholder image with the actual loaded image:

```
setImagePlaceholder(hotel) {
    this.$set(hotel, 'imgLoaded', false);

    const image = new Image();
    image.src = hotel.thumbUrl;

    image.onload = () => {
        hotel.imgLoaded = true;
    };
}
```

Don't know how I could make it any easier for you.

Answer (score -1):

Herre a simple [demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/8vn6xzfx/), you need to add the recurseve second try.

```
var img = new Image();

img.onload=function(){
     console.log('loaded!');
 };
 img.onerror = function(){
    console.log("error");
 }
 img.src='something';
```

Comment: Any Ideas how to implement this in Vue?