# Check if image is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you help me?

How can I check if img is fully loaded before set the src with this function below?

```
<img class="loadlater" data-src="path/to/image.ext"/>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".loadlater").each(function(index, element){
        $(element).attr("src", $(element).attr("data-src"));
    });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect image load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537469/detect-image-load)

Comment: But how can I check if the image is fully loaded before set the src?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is using the `onLoad` feature:

```
<img class="loadlater" data-src="path/to/image.ext" onLoad="function()"/>
```

This will call the function as soon as the element has loaded

Comment: _onLoad="function()"_ will start when the image is fully loaded?

Comment: yes, as soon as the element has loaded, it wall call the function (this works for all HTML elements)